# Docker installation failed on ubuntu 16- 4 3 server i386

Tags: docker, 32-bit

I have installed ubuntu-16.04.3-server-i386.

this command:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

only applies to the AMD64 architecture. Found that out the hard way. Which for some reason cannot be installed on my computer. Yes it is 64bit capable computer.  I am open to suggestions on changing my platform.

Comment: is you computer one of those rare ones that only supports 32 bit EFI?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is pretty simple - you need to install **x64** version of Ubuntu server. You need to do a **fresh install**, there is no way to update current installed OS.

The list of supported architectures can be found [here](https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-server-ubuntu).

Comment: For the fresh install, I'm looking at Ubunto versions here: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server. Just to be safe and to avoid having to do another fresh install, is it possible to recommend either Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS or Ubuntu Server 17.10?

Comment: @Chris, FYI: LTS version is supported for 5 years, thus 16.04.3 LTS (both server and desktop versions) will get repository updates until April 2021. Ordinary release, 17.10 for example, will be supported only for the period of 18 months. So in my opinion, 16.04.3 LTS is preferred. Or you can install 17.10 and after the release of 18.04 LTS upgrade your current OS to LTS. More details about terms of releases and support can be found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).